# problema al enviar datos con ajax a mysql

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

buen día tengo este pequeño problema y me gustaría que me den una mano estoy tratando de mandar datos a mi base de datos mediante ajax y me funcionan todos los mensajes y todas las alertas y cuando le doy a enviar dice que se envió todo bien pero no se agregan los datos a la base de datos. A continuación el código a ver donde me estoy equivocando.

este es el formulario

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <h1 class="page-header"><a id="jugador-add" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">Añadir Jugador</a></h1>
</div>
<!-- COMIENZO AJAX AGREGAR JUGADOR  -->
<!-- comienzo Modal-->            
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalj" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Añadir Jugador</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <form  method="post" id="forminsertar" name="forminsertar" role="form">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Nombre del Jugador</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Nombre del Jugador"name="jNombre" id="jNombre">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Apellido del Jugador</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Apellido del Jugador"name="jApellido" id="jApellido">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="jFecha" id="jFecha" type="date" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Cedula del Jugador</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Cedula del Jugador"name="jCedula" id="jCedula">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Direccion del Jugador</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Direccion del Jugador"name="jDireccion" id="jDireccion">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Ciudad del Jugador</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Ciudad del Jugador"name="jCiudad" id="jCiudad">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Telefono del Jugador</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Telefono del Jugador"name="jTelefono" id="jTelefono">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Estatura del Jugador</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Estatura del Jugador"name="jEstatura" id="jEstatura">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>numero del Jugador</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Numero Chaqueta del Jugador"name="jNumero" id="jNumero">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Equipo</label>
                      <select name="jrefEquipo" class="form-control" id="jrefEquipo">
                        <option value="0" selected>Sin Equipo</option>
                        <?php do { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row_DatosEquipo["idEquipo"]?>" ><?php echo $row_DatosEquipo["eNombre"]?></option>
                        <?php               
                          } while ($row_DatosEquipo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosEquipo)); 
                          ?>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Posicion</label>
                      <select name="jrefPosicion" class="form-control" id="jrefPosicion">
                        <option value="0" selected>Sin Posicion</option>
                        <?php do { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row_DatosPosicion["idPosicion"]?>" ><?php echo $row_DatosPosicion["pPosicion"]?></option>
                        <?php               
                          } while ($row_DatosPosicion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosPosicion)); 
                          ?>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Email</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Email"name="jEmail" id="jEmail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Contraseña</label>
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir Contraseña"name="jContraseña" id="jContraseña">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div  class="modal-footer">
                <!--bottones-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button> 
                <button id="aceptar_jugador" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>   
              </div>
              <!--bottones-->    
            </div>
            <!-- /.row (nested) -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- final Cabecera del modal-->
  </div>
  <!-- final Modal content-->
</div>
<!-- final Modal-->
```

este es el ajax

```
<script >

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jugador-add").click(function () {
        $("#myModalj").modal();





         $("#aceptar_jugador").unbind('click');
        $("#aceptar_jugador").click(function () {


        var jNombre = document.getElementById("jNombre").value;
        var jApellido = document.getElementById("jApellido").value;
        var jFecha = document.getElementById("jFecha").value;
        var jCedula = document.getElementById("jCedula").value;
        var jDireccion = document.getElementById("jDireccion").value;
        var jCiudad = document.getElementById("jCiudad").value;
        var jTelefono = document.getElementById("jTelefono").value;
        var jEstatura = document.getElementById("jEstatura").value;
        var jNumero = document.getElementById("jNumero").value;
        var jrefEquipo = document.getElementById("jrefEquipo").value;
        var jrefPosicion = document.getElementById("jrefPosicion").value;
        var jEmail = document.getElementById("jEmail").value;
        var jContraseña = document.getElementById("jContraseña").value;

        if ( jNombre == "" || jApellido == "" || jFecha == "" || jCedula =="" || jDireccion =="" || jCiudad =="" || jTelefono =="" || jEstatura =="" || jNumero =="" || jEmail =="" || jContraseña =="") {
        alert("Error: Todos los campos son obligatorios.");

      } else {
           $("#myModalj").modal('toggle');

        var params = {jNombre, jApellido, jFecha, jCedula, jDireccion, jCiudad, jTelefono, jEstatura, jNumero, jrefEquipo, jrefPosicion, jEmail, jContraseña}

         $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jugador-insert.php',
        data: params,
        async:true,

          success: function(respuesta) {

            alert("Informacion: Jugador creado correctamente!");
            location.reload();
               }

            });
            }
          });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

y este es el insert

```
<?php require_once('../Conexion/conexion.php');?>
<?php 



    $jNombre = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jNombre'], "text"); 
    $jApellido = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jApellido'], "text");
    $jFecha = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jFecha'], "date");
    $jCedula = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jCedula'], "int");
    $jDireccion = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jDireccion'], "text");
    $jCedula = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jCedula'], "int");
    $jTelefono = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jTelefono'], "int");
    $jEstatura = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jEstatura'], "int");
    $jNumero = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jNumero'], "int");
    $jrefEquipo = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jrefEquipo'], "int");
    $jrefPosicion = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jrefPosicion'], "int");
    $jEmail = GetSQLValueString($_POST['jEmail'], "text");
    $jContra = GetSQLValueString(md5($_POST['jContraseña']));

    $jregistro=date('Y-m-d');


    $sql="INSERT into tbljugadores (jNombre, jApellido, jFecha,  jCedula, jDireccion, jCiudad, jTelefono, jEstatura, jNumero, jrefEquipo, jrefPosicion, jEmail, jContraseña, jregistro)
            values ('$jNombre','$jApellido','$jFecha','$jCedula','$jDireccion','$jCiudad','$jTelefono','$jEstatura','$jNumero','$jrefEquipo','$jrefPosicion','$jEmail','$jContra','$jregistro')";
    echo mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 ?>
```

todo funciona bien hasta ahí pero no me guarda los datos a la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

El código en el servidor no encontrará nada en el POST, en tu variable `params` de Javascript debes poner cada valor así:

```
clave : valor
```

o sea, a la izquierda lo que sería la clave que usarás en el POST para obtener el valor: `$_POST["clave"]` te dará el dato que haya en `valor`.

Entonces, debes escribir `params`  así:

```
    var params = {
                    jNombre: jNombre, 
                    jApellido: jApellido, 
                    jFecha: jFecha, 
                    jCedula: jCedula, 
                    jDireccion: jDireccion, 
                    jCiudad: jCiudad, 
                    jTelefono: jTelefono, 
                    jEstatura: jEstatura, 
                    jNumero: jNumero, 
                    jrefEquipo: jrefEquipo, 
                    jrefPosicion: jrefPosicion, 
                    jEmail: jEmail, 
                    jContraseña: jContraseña
                }
```

Así sí, el `POST` tendrá sus datos, cada uno asociado a la clave de la izquierda.

Como recomendación, evita el uso de variables con `ñ` o palabras acentudas, lo digo por el caso de `jContraseña` ... a veces hay problemas de codificación y el uso de variables así puede afectar al código.

---

**Nota sobre la seguridad:** Tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Considera aplicar consultas preparadas para evitarlo.

Comment: aun asi no me funciona como lo tenia me funcionaba pero dejo de funcionar, si entro al insert en la base de dato me llena valores en null pero si lo envio por el formulario dice que se envio correcto pero no llega a la bd

Comment: @user93054 convendría que hagas un `print_r(·$_POST);` para verificar cómo están llegando los datos realmente. En el HTML debes verificar que cada elemento tenga el id correcto, ya que obtienes los valores por el id  en Javascript. También, al pasar cada dato a una función `GetSQLValueString` no se ve aquí lo que esa función hace con los datos. Son cosas que debes verificar. Cuando pases al uso de consultas preparadas podrás incluso prescindir de `GetSQLValueString`...